# Describe expression of $n$th derivative of a function on $x$ and $y$ axis.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

In order to calculate derivative of a function we use change in function :

$$\Delta f(x) = f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)$$

Where both $f(x+\Delta x)$ and $f(x)$ are points on $y$ axis.

Is it possible to show  $n$th change in function on the $y$ axis? For example, consider the second derivative expression
:
$$\frac{\Delta ^ 2f(x)}{\Delta x^2} = \frac{f(x+\Delta x)-2f(x)+f(x-\Delta x)}{\Delta x^2}$$

How can we substantiate this expression is really a formula of the second derivative by using $x$ and $y$ axes?

Answer (score 0):

Second derivative is just the rate of change of the rate of change. So if we want to find $\frac{\Delta ^2 f(x)}{\Delta x}$, we can just find the difference between two adjacent rates of change: between $x-\Delta x$ and $x$, then between $x$ and then $x+\Delta x$. So we get for the difference between each rate of change (using your formula for first derivative)

The rate of change on the first interval is $\frac{\Delta f(x)}{\Delta x}=\frac{f(x)-f(x-\Delta x)}{\Delta x}$

and then the second one will be
$\frac{\Delta f(x)}{\Delta x}=\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$.

So now we want to find the difference between the two rates of change to get our $\Delta (\frac{\Delta f(x)}{\Delta x}) =\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x) - [f(x)-f(x-\Delta x)]}{\Delta x} =\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-2f(x)+f(x-\Delta x)}{\Delta x}$

Finally we can put our $\frac{\Delta ^2 f(x)}{\Delta x}$ all over $\Delta x$ to get our second derivative formula.
$\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-2f(x)+f(x-\Delta x)}{\Delta x^2}$

Comment: Well the numerator of the expression is clear. But how about the $\Delta x^2$. Where did it come from?

Comment: the change in first derivative was $\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-2f(x)+f(x-\Delta x)}{\Delta x}$, so if you put the change over the change in x ($\Delta x$) you get change in first derivative with respect to x, aka second derivative. This is :  $\frac{\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-2f(x)+f(x-\Delta x)}{\Delta x}}{\Delta x}= \frac{f(x+\Delta x)-2f(x)+f(x-\Delta x)}{\Delta x^2}$